# Question about how to (mathematically) interpret averages with the Feynman-Kac formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, wick-rotation

I'm trying to understand the Feynman-Kac formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) for the Wick-rotated Feynman path integral. Would it be correct to say that $$\langle \phi\rangle=\lim_{n\to \inf}([{\prod_{j=1}^n (\int_{V_j}d\mu_{x_j})](1-\frac{S_E[\vec x]}{n}/\hbar)^n}\phi[\vec x]),$$ with $\mu_{x_j}$ a Wiener measure, $S_E$ the Euclidean action, $V_j$ some region of integration (dependent upon $x_j$) and $\phi$ either a wavefunction or field operator? If not, what is the correct formula? (Please do not say: $\int e^{-S_E/\hbar}\phi(x')d[\mu_x(x')]$ as that ignores the details about the integration that I'm trying to understand...)